# Css div ease in and out

Tags: css

I am trying to make my div fade in and out with only css. Could someone please help me.

```css
.overlay {
display: none;
}

.image:hover .overlay { 
box-sizing: border-box; 
display: block; 
height: 100%; 
left: 0; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
position: absolute;
top: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;   
}
```

Comment: You will want to look into css animations. Here's a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `opacity` property that can be animated with [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Try the following:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; /* for compatibility with older versions of Opera */
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; /* for compatibility with IE and Edge */
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; /* for compatibility with Firefox */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; /* for compatibility with Chrome, Safari... */
}

#container:hover>.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Try hovering over the image:</p>
<div id="container">
  <img>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Note: `<img>` is a self-contained tag. That is, it cannot contain elements.
You will need a wrapping `div` as shown in the example with a container that contains both your image and the overlay.

I hope this helps.